# what's a clean way of finding which common elements exist in a set of n arrays?

Tags: ruby, set, refactoring

I'm going through a table in my database that has a lot of optional columns. I'm wanting to find the columns which have data in every record in my database.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do is as follows:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] & [1,2,3,4] & [1,2,3] & [1,2]
#=> [1,2]
```

However, what I'm trying to do is run this type of operation for thousands of records. What's a clean way to accomplish this? I have the feeling that ruby might have some bespoke methods for this sort of thing.

Here's what I was about to do before I decided to write this question:

```
sets_of_columns_with_data = TableName.all.map(&:attributes).map do |attrs| 
    attrs.select {|k,v| v}
end.map(&:keys)
```

So at this point, if you were following the above code, `columns_with_data` is now the equivalent of this:

```
sets_of_columns_with_data = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [1,2,3,4],
  [1,2,3]
  [1,2]
 ]
```

A messy way to do this I guess would look something like this:

```
always_used = sets_of_columns_with_data.first
sets_of_columns_with_data.each do |columns_with_data|
  always_used = always_used & columns_with_data
end
```

What's the clean, ruby-way to do something like this?

Thanks

NOTE:

I'm keeping the business logic for sake of clarity, but generally this is not the best solution when you have SQL available to you.

Comment: *"I'm wanting to find the columns which have data in every record in my database"* - seem like a database query would be more appropriate. What kind of database is that?

Comment: Please share the result of `puts TableName.first.inspect`.

Comment: sqlite. you're probably right in this case, but I guess the way I've set up the question its more about finding a bespoke ruby method that finds common elements in a set of sets...

Comment: If you're looking for a general answer, you should probably remove the database specific details from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves the actual problem, but to apply a binary operation, you can use `reduce`:

```
sets_of_columns_with_data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2]
]

sets_of_columns_with_data.reduce(:&) #=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: The `map` spaghetti in building `sets_of_columns_with_data` forces me to think that there could be less expensive solution with `pluck`-`reduce`.

Comment: @mudasobwa It is not clear how the OP's code that derives `sets_of_columns_with_data` works, but all that code in the block can be put directly inside the `reduce` block.

Comment: @sawa That is exactly what I wanted to say :)

Comment: it is fairly clear if you just run the code. I didn't bother showing the actual column data b/c its irrelevant. `#attributes` spits out a hash of k/v pairs for a given record, #select plucks out the k/v pairs that have values other than nil or false, then you pluck the column names, then you run this handy reduce command